# get/post in a generic handler

Tags: asp.net, post, get, generic-handler

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

which of these two is get and which is post?
It is used in a generic handler (.ashx file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true/false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public bool UseHttpGet { set; get; }
Member of System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute
```

**Summary**:
Gets or sets a value that indicates whether to invoke the method by using HTTP GET.

**Returns**:
true if the method is invoked by using the HTTP GET command; false if the method is invoked by using the HTTP POST command. The default is false.

we can make both get and post methods

Answer (score 1):

ScriptMethod allows you to call the method in Get scenarios.  Which otherwise need to be called via POST

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx)